# ngIf else not working

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-ng-if

I keep getting the error

> Can't bind to 'ngIfElse' since it isn't a known property of 'ul'.

I'm sure somewhere I am making a stupid mistake but can't find it.

```xml
<ul *ngIf="!finished; else elseBlock" id='time'>
  <li id='hour' class="chart"  data-percent="100"><span>{{hour}} </span></li>
  <li id='min' class="chart" data-percent="100"><span>{{minute}}</span></li>
  <li id='second' class="chart" data-percent="100"><span>{{second}}</span></li>
</ul>
<ng-template  #elseBlock>  <h4 id='time'>DONE</h4> </ng-template>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code. I would make sure you are running Angular 4.0. As the above posters are correct in that this is not supported in angular 2.

Answer (score 5):

Angular 2 does not support Esle, you have 2 options:

1: using positive case:

```xml
<ul *ngIf="!finished" id="time">
  <li id='hour' class="chart"  data-percent="100"><span>{{hour}} </span></li>
  <li id='min' class="chart" data-percent="100"><span>{{minute}}</span></li>
  <li id='second' class="chart" data-percent="100"><span>{{second}}</span</li>
</ul>
<h4 id="time" *ngIf="finished"> <!-- this -->
  DONE
</h4>
```

2: update your app to Angular 4:

On Linux/Mac:

```
npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router,animations}@latest typescript@latest --save
```

On Windows:

```
npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save
```

> If you rely on Animations, import the new BrowserAnimationsModule from
>   @angular/platform-browser/animations in your root NgModule. Without
>   this, your code will compile and run, but animations will trigger an
>   error. Imports from @angular/core were deprecated, use imports from
>   the new package import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate }
>   from '@angular/animations';.

http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html

Answer (score 2):

The `ng-if` directive only handles the positive case.  For the negative case (the `else`) use a separate block:

```xml
<ul ng-if="!finished" id="time">
    <li id='hour'   class="chart" data-percent="100"><span>{{hour}} </span></li>
    <li id='min'    class="chart" data-percent="100"><span>{{minute}}</span></li>
    <li id='second' class="chart" data-percent="100"><span>{{second}}</span></li>
</ul>
<ng-if="finished">
    <h4 id='time'>DONE</h4>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: while angular version 2 doesn't support ng-if-else, but angular version 4 has this feature now.